# Kohana - adding values to the query before ORM::Save

Tags: php, kohana

I am using the ORM to save  the user registration data into the database.  The code is as follows.

```
if ($_POST) {
    $user = Model::factory('member');
    $post = $user->validate_create($_POST); 
    if ($post->check()) {
        $user->values($post);
        $user->save();
        // redirect to create gallery.
    }
}
```

I have some values such as the `UserType` which is not part of the `$_POST` but has to be saved in the `members` table as part of the user registration.  Is it a good idea to alter the values of `$post` and add `UserType` to it or is there any other recommended methods for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's ok to alter the `$post` since it's just an array with the values taken from request now.

You can do it either by editing the `$post` array:

```
$post['usertype'] = 'customer';
$user->values($post);
$user->save();
```

Or you can set the value to your ORM object directly:

```
$user->values($post);
$user->usertype = 'customer';
$user->save();
```

Both should be fine

Answer (score 0):

You can use hidden inputs in your form. For example:

```
Form::hidden('usertype', 'customer');
```

If you don't want to change $_POST array.
If you want to check is user sending $_POST request, use Kohana's method:

```
if($this->request->method() === Request::POST) {}
```

instead of:

```
if($_POST)
```

By the way, get a $_POST data in this way:

```
$post = $this->request->post();
```